# Using tax_query reverses my post_type argument in a custom WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

I'm using a custom query to pull some posts from a custom post type. I'm having problems with it so I used print_r on my WP_Query object and I found something strange.

```
my query has these arguments:
'post_type' => 'event'
    ,'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'event-categories'
                    ,'field' => 'id'
                    ,'terms' => 72
                    ,'operator' => 'IN'
                )
    )
    ,'order' => 'ASC'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and when I remove the tax_query portion I get all my posts, but when I include it I get none. I'm positive I have more than one post with the taxonomy ID of 72. When I look at my print_r($query) with the post type in, I see this:

```
WP_Query Object
(
[query_vars] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => Array
            (
                [0] => media_player
                [1] => ada_slides
                [2] => closings
                [3] => staff
                [4] => post
                [5] => page
            )
```

All of my post types are listed except for the one I wanted, event. If I take out tax_query from my args, it looks like this:

```
WP_Query Object
(
[query_vars] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => event
        [order] => ASC
```

...and so on

Also, if I change my operator to NOT IN, it searches the correct post type but excludes the category I want to search for.

Why would using a tax_query argument seemingly invalidate my post_type argument and instead include all post types but the one I wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a plugin conflict. I had turned off all plugins at one point to no noticeable benefit, but then turned a few back on so I could run some other things on the site I was working with.

The trouble was with the Easy Custom Content Types plugin (a *very* handy plugin) and I'm checking in with the developer of it. It looks like I may not have the latest version of it either so maybe he's already fixed it.

Comment: The problem is caused by a function in the plugin that helps to resolve taxonomy archive 404s. It has a couple of issues, and because of them, there is a setting to disable the function. Go to Content Types > Settings and check "Disable Taxonomy Archive Fix".