# Custom Widget WP_Query problem

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, widgets, tax-query

I have everything working on my widget except the results! I created a taxonomy called country names that we use for several custom post types. I created this widget to display tour guides (CPT) from the selected country.

The widget is working properly on the back end, but I am getting no results on the front end (ie. "No listing found"). I have echoed the $instance to the screen and it is correct, so my args or query must be incorrect. Can anyone tell why?

Here is the code:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {  
extract( $args );   
$title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
$thiscountry = $instance['thiscountry'];
$before_widget = '<!-- '.$thiscountry.' -->';
echo $before_widget;
if ( $title ) {
    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
}
$this->getTourGuides($thiscountry);
echo $after_widget;
}

function getTourGuides($thiscountry) { //html
global $post;
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => array( 'tourguides' ),
'tax_query' => array(
      array(
       'taxonomy'      => 'countryname',
       'field' => 'name', // also tried 'slug'
        'terms' => $thiscountry,
    ),    
  ),
);

//echo $thiscountry;
$listings = new WP_Query( $args);
if($listings->found_posts > 0) {
    echo '<ul class="guides_widget">';
        while ($listings->have_posts()) {
            /* Get custom post type fields */
            $ecpt_website = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_website', true );

            $listings->the_post();              
            $listItem = '<li>';
            $listItem .= '<a href="' . $ecpt_website . '">';
            $listItem .= get_the_title() . '</a>';
            $listItem .= '</li>';
            echo $listItem;
        } // end while
    echo '</ul>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }else{
    echo '<p style="padding:25px;">No listing found</p>';
  }
}
```

Code for the instance:

```
// constructor
function __construct() {
parent::__construct(
    'btn_tour_guides_by_country', // Base ID
    'BTN Tour Guides by Country', // Name
    array('description' => __( 'Display List of Tour Guides by Country in a Sidebar'))
   );
}
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
$instance = $old_instance;
$instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
$instance['thiscountry'] = strip_tags($new_instance['thiscountry']);
return $instance;
}

// widget form creation
function form($instance) {
if( $instance) {
    $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
    $thiscountry = esc_attr($instance['thiscountry']);
} else {
    $title = 'Tour Operators';
    $thiscountry = '';
}
?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:'); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php 
echo $title; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('thiscountry'); ?>"><?php _e('Country:'); ?></label>
    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('thiscountry'); ?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('thiscountry'); ?>">
        <?php 
        $taxonomy = 'countryname';
        $queried_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var($taxonomy) );
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
        //echo $term->slug;
        if ( $terms !== 0 ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {?> 
         <?php                     
            echo '<option '.selected($instance['thiscountry'], $term->name).' value="' . $term->name . '" id="' . $term->name . '">', $term->name, '</option>';     

               ?>

                  <?php                
            }
        }
         ?>

        <?php ?>
    </select>
    </p>

<?php
}
```

Comment: What's the code for selecting and saving `$instance['thiscountry']`?

Comment: I added it above. The plugin is working fine in the backend and my echo seemd to be giving me the correct results. I just tried a print_r for $instance and found these two entries:

Comment: the output works fine here with WP_Query args, maybe a spelling mistake on taxonomy or posttype?

Comment: ooops, I hit enter. I am seeing  [countryname] =>  (this is blank) and [thiscountry] => Bahamas ( which is correct for that page and sidebar).

Comment: If I take out the tax_query I get the full list of tour guides for all countries, so it seems it has to be in the tax query

Comment: look at `$listings->request` after the query is run and you'll see the query that was sent to the database.

Comment: Milo, I don't know what you mean, sorry. I did a print_r for $listings and I did find something I thought was odd. If I take out the tax_query I see tourguides as the only post type listed in query_vars, but If I  put the tax_query back in, the query_vars array lists all of the post types EXCEPT for tourguides. Is that odd?

Comment: Milo, I get it. Yes, it's exactly what I was saying above that part of the SELECT is AND posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'sites', 'thetours', 'post', 'page')  If I take out the tax query it says... AND posts.post_type = 'tourguides'. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here. They were having the exact same problem:
[Using tax_query reverses my post_type argument in a custom WP_Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50928/using-tax-query-reverses-my-post-type-argument-in-a-custom-wp-query?rq=1)

It is a problem with the Easy Content Types plugin. Pippin, the author of this plugin wrote the following:  The problem is caused by a function in the plugin that helps to resolve taxonomy archive 404s. It has a couple of issues, and because of them, there is a setting to disable the function. Go to Content Types > Settings and check "Disable Taxonomy Archive Fix". – Pippin May 11 '12 at 0:03

Comment: Ha! that fix didn't work - waiting to hear from support.